# Named Pipes using C++

Tags: c++, winapi, ipc, pipe, named-pipes

I am trying to create a named pipe server to write to the pipe without the client.
What I am trying to do is

1)CreateNamedPipe
2)I dont want the client to connect right now
3)The pipe will be written by the server and later the pipe will be read.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Please Help if you have anything about this issue.

Comment: ive recently used named pipes, and i dont think that pipes can be used for read/write unless both ends of the pipe are connected.

Comment: You have certainly tried it in a few ways before asking, right? So can you tell what you tried and how it failed?

Comment: I made a pipe server and a pipe client.After creating the pipe i have to wait for the client to connect to the pipe once connected the server writes to the pipe and client reads the pipe.

Comment: In the other case i create a pipe and dont wait for the client to connect and then try to write to the pipe then it gives a error 218 "Waiting for a process to open the other end of the pipe. "

Answer (score 1):

You need to have separate thread that will wait on given named pipe using `ConnectNamedPipe`. As soon as client connects, ConnectNamedPipe would return. Communicate using that newly connected pipe (probably spawn a new thread for this new connection), then return back to `ConnectNamedPipe` for another pipe connection.

Comment: But it would have to wait for the client to connect.

Comment: Why is that a problem? Just write into some kind of buffer until the client connects (e.g. `std::stringstream` if you have strings), and once the client connects, write the current content of your buffer to the pipe, and write future messages directly to the pipe.

Comment: @smerlin I do have that case where if the client never connects i can write it in a file but i just want to know that is it possible to create a pipe and only write to that pipe without the client connecting to the pipe.